# Одно модальное окно с разным содержимым

Tags: html, bootstrap

Пишу html страницу с использованием bootstrap на которой есть кнопки регистрации и авторизации пользователей. При нажатии на кнопку всплывает модальное окно с формой того или иного действия. Формы в дальнейшем с использованием ajax отправляются для обработки на сервер. На самой странице каждое модальное окно оформлено отдельно:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="enter">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="login" placeholder="Имя пользователя"/>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="password" placeholder="Пароль"/>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Отмена</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="enter_sumbit">Войти</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="reg">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="login" placeholder="Имя пользователя"/>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="password" placeholder="Пароль"/>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
    <div id="reg-modal-footer" class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Отмена</button>
        <button id="reg_sumbit" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Зарегистрироваться</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Содержимое окон очень похоже. Возник вопрос:

Как сделать так, что бы было одно модальное окно, а содержимое менялось в зависимости от нажатой кнопки?

Comment: Возможно, вам подойдет [пример с сайта самого бутстрапа](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target).

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko, ссылка из предыдущего комментария ведет на раздел "Varying modal content based on trigger button", где 1 модальное окно и 3 кнопки. В зависимости от нажатой кнопки в открывшемся окне появляется различный текст. После html кода примера идет блок с js, который выполняет подстановку текста в модальное окно

Comment: @AndrewB, да, прошу прощения, сразу не увидела! Хорошее решение!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вариант 1: С помощью JavaScript динамически строить содержимое внутри окна.

Вариант 2: Через ajax подгружать содержимое форм и помещать его внутрь окна.

Comment: Как это делается через аякс? "подгружать содержимое форм" откуда подгружать?

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko Мб как-то так `$.ajax(....).then(function(data){ var res = data.d; $("formBlock).html(res);  })`. Дальше (если надо)  можно прописать условие поиска (что нам пришло) и навесить необходимые листенеры (обработка формы, кнопка и т.п.).  Куда стучаться - это уже вопрос специфичный т.к. можно данные тащить с api, php. А js для обработки можно и не грузить отдельно, а все в одном main.js хранить заранее. Только вешать листенеры по id чтобы наверняка не промахнуться. Хотя я уверен, что вы получше меня это знаете)

Answer (score 4):

Сделал на **jQuery**. При клике на кнопку, вставляем нужное сожержимое в наше окно.

```js
$("#button-1").click(function() {
   $(".modal").toggleClass("hidden").html('<input type="text" placeholder="Имя пользователя"><br><input type="password" placeholder="Пароль"><br><button>Отмена</button><button>Войти</button>');
});
$("#button-2").click(function() {
   $(".modal").toggleClass("hidden").html('<input type="text" placeholder="Имя пользователя"><br><input type="password" placeholder="Пароль"><br><input type="email" placeholder="Email"><br><button>Отмена</button><button>Зарегистрироваться</button></div>');
});
```

```css
button {
    width: 140px;
    height: 30px;
    color: aqua;
    background: blue;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
    margin: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 24px;
    width: 126px;
    padding: 2px 6px;
    margin: 6px;
    outline: none;
}
.hidden {
    opacity: 0; 
}
.modal {
    width: 274px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="button-1">Кнопка 1</button>
<button id="button-2">Кнопка 2</button>

<div class="modal hidden"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Прошу сильно не ругаться, код написан на коленке, но должен ответить на Ваш вопрос.

```
$('#btn-enter').click(function () {
    $('#reg').css({'display': 'none'});
    $('#enter').css({'display': 'block'});
});
$('#btn-reg').click(function () {
    $('#reg').css({'display': 'block'});
    $('#enter').css({'display': 'none'});
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jqezjpjx/

Comment: Эм.. Но зачем?? Чем копирование разметки из двух источников лучше, чем два окна?

Comment: На самом деле - действительно - ничем. Просто это была самая первая мысль, которая пришла в голову. Сейчас сделаю лучше :)

Comment: Qwertiy, все. Спасибо за совет!

Comment: "что бы было одно модальное окно, а содержимое менялось в зависимости от нажатой кнопки"

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko по факту пользователь будет видеть 1 окно.

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko, скажите, пожалуйста, Вы хотите, чтобы на странице совсем не было содержимого каждого из окон? Потому что самый простой пример - переключение отображения окон. Можно просто копировать содержимое этих окон в одно модальное окно, пример кода был в прошлой версии ответа ( https://jsfiddle.net/rarwv9ws/ ). Так же можно хранить окна на другой странице, генерировать их через php, если есть необходимость и через AJAX загружать их и отображать на первой странице.

Comment: Самый идеальный вариант это через ajax, но почему-то упорно ни кто не хочет делиться (с новичками) как это можно сделать! 
По поводу страницы `<button id="button-1">Кнопка 1</button>
<button id="button-2">Кнопка 2</button>

<div class="modal hidden"></div>` вот что должно быть на странице, а у же по клику на кнопку открывается полноценное окно! 

А то что Вы предлагаете какой-то венегрет!!!